# Making my drop-down menus accessible when only using the keyboard

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, accessibility

At the moment my dropdown menus only appear when the user rolls over them.

I would like it so if you pressed the TAB key the drop down would appear in the same way

My menu is based on the following tutroial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

The only thing I have updated code wise is the style in CSS

Below is a section of my menu:

HTML:

```
 <ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="about-us.php" class="drop">About us</a>
            <div class="dropdown_1column align_left">
                 <div class="col_1">
                      <ul class="simple">
                          <li><a href="why-choose-us.php">Why choose us</a></li>
                          <li><a href="our-office.php">Our office</a></li>
                       </ul>   
                  </div>
              </div>
    </li>

<li><a href="how-we-help.php" class="drop">How we help</a>
     <div class="dropdown_2columns align_left">
          <div class="col_2">
               <h3 class="link-menu-title"><a href="#">Technology</a></h3>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="dynamic-purchasing.php" style="width:270px;">Dynamic purchasing with Matrix</a></li>
                        <li><a href="process.php">Process</a></li>
                        <li><a href="interfacing.php">Interfacing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="implementation.php">Implementation</a></li>
                    </ul>   
             </div>

       <div class="col_2">
                 <h3 class="link-menu-title"><a href="#">Professional Support Services</a></h3>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="discovery.php">Discovery</a></li>
                         <li><a href="account-management.php">Account management</a></li>
                         <li><a href="business-management.php" style="width:270px;">Business management</a></li>
                         <li><a href="supplier-management.php"> Supplier management</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
              </div>

            </li>

        </ul>
```

and the CSS

```
#menu li.menu-icon:hover {
    background-color:#212121;
    border:0px;
}


a#home span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
}

#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:730px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    height:73px;


    /* Background color and gradients */



    /* Borders */

    border: 0px solid #002232;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
    margin-right:12px;
    margin-top:25px;
    border:none;


}

#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #11A7E6;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #11A7E6;


    /* Rounded corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;

}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

.medium #menu li a {
    font-size:16px;
}

.large #menu li a {
    font-size:20px;
}

.medium #menu li .drop, .large #menu li .drop {
    padding-right: 0px;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;

}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-left:3px;
}

.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-top:10px solid #11A7E6;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#2D2D2D;


    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;

}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
.col_4,
.col_5 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:130px;}
.col_2 {width:270px;}
.col_3 {width:410px;}
.col_4 {width:550px;}
.col_5 {width:690px;}


#menu .menu_right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#menu li .align_right {
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li:hover .align_right {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

#menu p, #menu h2, #menu h3, #menu ul li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height:21px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;

}
#menu h2 {
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin:7px 0 3px 0;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;

}
#menu h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:7px 0 3px 0;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;

}


#menu p {
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0 0 30px 0;

}

#menu li:hover div a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#0ea4e3;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}

.medium #menu li:hover div a {
    font-size:15px;
}

.large #menu li:hover div a {
    font-size:19px;
}

#menu li:hover div h2.link-menu-title a{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
}

#menu li:hover div h3.link-menu-title a{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
}

.medium #menu li:hover div h3.link-menu-title a{
    font-size:17px;
}

.large #menu li:hover div h3.link-menu-title a{
    font-size:21px;
}


#menu li:hover div a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: #474747;


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the tutorial, it is not really a good starting point to make fully keyboard accessible. Unfortunately it isn't just a matter of showing the drop-downs when pressing tab.

Once you get past a couple of items in each drop-down it it not a good thing for keyboard users to have to tab through every option.

There are two main ways to make this type of menu accessible:

1. **Traditional method:** Make each top level link go through to a landing page that includes the links from the menu, and *hide the drop-downs* from keyboard use.
2. **HTML5 (new) method:** Use WAI-ARIA markup and lots of scripting to enable full keyboard accessibility.

The traditional method if fairly easy to do, you just need to properly hide the menus that are off-screen using `display: none;` on the classes starting `.dropdown_1column`. The means keyboard users won't tab through the sub-menus.

And then use `display: block` to show the sub-menus on hover (not focus), where the CSS starts:

```
#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column
```

To achieve the HTML5/new method I would start with Adobe's open-sourced "[Accessible Mega Menu](http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/)". It would be a huge amount of work to do this from scratch, and unless you know how to test with a wide range of user-agents, it is unlikely to work as well as Adobe's.

Comment: I checked out the mega menu and it wasnt working properly in firefox. I have added my markup and style to the question if that helps, thank you!

Comment: I tried the Adobe one in FF, seems to work fine. They use it on their main site, so I'd be surprised if there were browser issues. After a quick look at your markup, I can't see anything to change in my answer - either hide the sub-menus properly (display: none), or use a full WAI-ARIA version like the Adobe one.

Comment: If you are saying that you have to focus li to display the submenu and then press the tab again, you are wrong. 'focus' event doesn't buble up. The moment you press tab after focusing the li, the li loses focus and the submenu disappears.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I had tested it and it seemed to work, but I must have changed something else. I've removed that option and shifted emphasis to the things I would recommend.

Comment: @AlastairC Great answer, thank you! What do you think about the example code provided by w3.org instead of the Adobe mega menu? https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html

Comment: @Andreas The W3C example is intended to demonstrate the ARIA pattern for a menu bar. That's actually a slightly different things to a website navigation. If you are creating an web app that looks like Word, then a 'menu' is appropriate. If you are creating a website navigation, I'd use the Adobe one.

Answer (score 0):

please upload your markup and styles. 
Anyways here is a sample menu that works on tab.

```
  .dropdown {
       position: relative;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 110%;
  }

 .dropdown ul {
      position: absolute;
      top: -100%;
      left: 100%;
      display: none;
      background-color: inherit;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
 }

 .dropdown ul li {
      position: relative;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 5px 0;
      background-color: inherit;
 }

 .dropdown ul li a {
      display: block;
      padding: 3px 10px;
 }

 .dropdown ul li a:hover {
      background-color: #18b6f2 !important;
  }

  .dropdown ul li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
      top: 0;
      background-color: inherit; 
  }

  .dropdown ul li:hover > a {
      background-color: #85ddff;
  }

  .dropdown:focus > ul {
      display: block;
  }
```

// markup

```
    <div class="dropdown" style="background-color: white;" tabindex="1">
    <a>Menu</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Fruits</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Apple</a></li>
                <li><a>Orange</a></li>
                <li><a>Grape</a></li>
                <li><a>Banana</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Vegetables</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Lemon</a></li>
                <li><a>Cucumber</a></li>
                <li><a>Melon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul> 
</div>
```

you need to give a tabindex value to make an element focusible ( which is not focusible by default).. Then you css3 :focus selector to trigger when the element is in focus.

Might be able to help if you write down your exact requirement

Comment: Thank you for this, I have now updated my question to include the mark up and styles as requested

Comment: You want the sub-menus to be accessible by tab??

Comment: Here i sthe site: http://www.matrix-scm.com/ you can see if you mouse over the top menus the dropdowns appear. However if you TAB accross them they dont. I would like it so as you TAB the dropdown menu appears and then you can carry on tabbing down them

Comment: You cannot do a complete tabbed menu using pure css. The problem is that focus event do not bubble up. So when the child is focused the parent loses focus and becomes invisible. But you can do a near perfect one. Give me some time. Ill put up a demo.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a demo. This is the closest you could with pure css.

```
<section class="header">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="dropdown" />
                    <a>Menu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="dropdown" />
                    <a>Menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="dropdown" />
                    <a>Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="dropdown" />
                    <a>Menu 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="dropdown" />
                    <a>Menu 5</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a tabindex="1">Submenu 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </section>
```

css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
.header .dropdown {
  margin: 50px 0 0 300px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.dropdown {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown > ul {
  display: block !important;
  background-color: black !important;
}
.dropdown > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown > ul > li input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dropdown > ul > li input[type="radio"]:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown > ul > li input[type="radio"]:focus ~ a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  width: 200%;
}
.dropdown ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.dropdown ul li a:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #0bd2f6;
}
.dropdown ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: But this obviously have certain problems. 1) you have to press tab to get the menu into focus (indicated by a white border at the bottom).

Comment: 2) You have to navigate the level-1 menu after focusing the first one using the left and right arrow keys.

Comment: Then tab would move to each submenu. Another problem is that hiding the menu is a little bit complicated. Im trying.

Comment: You fiddle around with this one.

Comment: Applying tabindex of 1 to multiple items is not valid, I think you mean "0", or 1, 2, 3 etc. http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#focus_tabindex Also, you shouldn't need tabindex on links at all, they are focusable by default. Keyboard users would be better off with either of the options outlined in my answer.

Comment: tabindex is just another index. browsers by default moves in the order they appear in the hierarchy. if you don't want to control the order you may give any positive value. I just gave them to make them focusible and not control the order. And if you din't know anchor tag (a) can be focused by default if you specify an href attribute. I din't give href. Read the solution and understand it. Then jump to conclusions.

Comment: If you want to generate your menu html using script you will have to have a variable storing the index values which is more complicated.

Comment: And you cannot be straight forward always. This is a bit hackish. You may use them without fear of browser support. Think out of the box

Comment: Ok, you are right that without an href an <a> is not focusable. I didn't notice that becuase it would be very odd to create a menu that doesn't go anywhere! It also doesn't fit the question. The reason you should use "0" instead of "1" is that placing the menu in the page would not over-ride the default tab-order of the other elements. Giving it a positive value DOES override the order, as per the spec. This is more than a bit hackish, again, either of the options outlined my answer would be better for keyboard users.

Comment: If you are saying that you have to focus li to display the submenu and then press the tab again, you are wrong. 'focus' event doesn't buble up. The moment you press tab after focusing the li, the li loses focus and the submenu disappears.